# RAID drives attached to separate devices

Tags: mount, raid, openwrt

Somehow, the two drives in my RAID 1 configuration have become attached two devices (`md0`,`md127`):

```
~# lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,STATE,FSTYPE,MODEL,SERIAL,UUID,LABEL
NAME          SIZE MOUNTPOINT STATE   FSTYPE            MODEL            SERIAL     UUID                                 LABEL
sda           1.8T            running linux_raid_member ST32000542AS                69c415bb-716b-8e0b-b03d-721888a9cb05 turris:0
`-md0         1.8T                    btrfs                                         47039540-3842-4b2b-be2b-b8f76e88189b 
sdb           1.8T            running linux_raid_member ST32000542AS                69c415bb-716b-8e0b-b03d-721888a9cb05 turris:0
`-md127       1.8T /mnt/raid          btrfs                                         47039540-3842-4b2b-be2b-b8f76e88189b
```

Why did this happen?  How do I get them back to a single device (`md0`)?

** edit **

`mdadm -E /dev/sda`:

```
~# mdadm -E /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 69c415bb:716b8e0b:b03d7218:88a9cb05
           Name : turris:0  (local to host turris)
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 23 11:52:07 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766720 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4ed3485a:ce6205f4:ecd1f9d0:6e4fb2b5

    Update Time : Wed Oct 11 21:18:53 2017
       Checksum : 8a845e99 - correct
         Events : 623


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

`mdadm -E /dev/sdb`:

```
~# mdadm -E /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 69c415bb:716b8e0b:b03d7218:88a9cb05
           Name : turris:0  (local to host turris)
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 23 11:52:07 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766720 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 7c8a1f7a:184b254c:1b25397c:8162faa4

    Update Time : Wed Oct 11 05:58:52 2017
       Checksum : 9d058b99 - correct
         Events : 345


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

`mdadm -D /dev/md0`:

```
~# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 23 11:52:07 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Oct 11 21:18:53 2017
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : turris:0  (local to host turris)
           UUID : 69c415bb:716b8e0b:b03d7218:88a9cb05
         Events : 623

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       0        0        1      removed
```

`mdadm -D /dev/md127`:

```
~# mdadm -D /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 23 11:52:07 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Oct 11 05:58:52 2017
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : turris:0  (local to host turris)
           UUID : 69c415bb:716b8e0b:b03d7218:88a9cb05
         Events : 345

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
```

** edit 1 **

Contents of `/etc/rc.local`:

```
# Put your custom commands here that should be executed once
# the system init finished. By default this file does nothing.

# Disable NCQ (fix RAID issue)
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/queue_depth
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/queue_depth
# /fix

# start RAID array
mdadm --assemble --scan

exit 0
```

Contents of `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=turris:0 UUID=69c415bb:716b8e0b:b03d7218:88a9cb05
```

Contents (somewhat redacted) of `/etc/aliases`:

```
root: cra***@*****.com
```

Comment: Is it a hardware raid (as "md127" suggests) or `mdadm` based raid?

Comment: @MLu, the fact that it is assigned the number 127 in no way indicates that it is a hardware raid.  That simply means that it is part of an array that is not described in /etc/mdadm.conf.  @craig, please add the output of `mdadm -E /dev/sda` and `mdadm -E /dev/sdb` to your question, as well as `mdadm -D /dev/md0` and `mdadm -D /dev/md127`.

Comment: @MLu, it's a mdadm-based RAID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Events : 623
Events : 345
```

At this point, your two drives are sufficiently out of sync that there's no easy way to get them back together.  Assuming the event counts accurately reflect the relative age of the data on the drives, I recommend wiping `/dev/sdb` and re-adding it to `/dev/md0`:

1. Make sure you've got an up-to-date backup of your data.
2. Bring down `/dev/md127`: `umount /mnt/raid`, `mdadm --stop /dev/md127`
3. Make `/dev/sdb` no longer look like a RAID member: `wipefs -a /dev/sdb` (the quick way) or `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` (the thorough way).
4. Add it to `/dev/md0` as a new device: `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb`
5. Wait for the array to rebuild.
6. While you're waiting, turn on monitoring for failures: `nano -w /etc/mdadm.conf` and add the line `MAILADDR your.email@address.com` somewhere towards the end, then activate the `mdadm` monitoring service (this is distro-specific).
7. Activate `/dev/md0`: `mdadm --run /dev/md0` (may not be needed) followed by `mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid`.

As to what caused it, I'm guessing that at one point you had a transient failure of `/dev/sdb` (Seagate drives tend to do this) and it fell out of the array until the next time you restarted your computer.  Since the event counts differed, `mdadm` wasn't able to put the two drives into a single RAID-1 array, and instead decided to create two single-drive RAID-1 arrays.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to perform step 7 immediately after step 4, but if you're running RAID, you really should be monitoring its status as well.

Comment: I was using `mdadm --assemble --scan` in the `/etc/rc.local` file to start the array.  Will creating the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file supplant the need to do this?

Comment: You'll still need to run `mdadm` to get it to assemble the array.  A properly-configured `mdadm.conf` simply makes the process more controllable.

Comment: Is there a way to test the `MAILADDR` property of the `mdadm.conf` file to ensure that it is working as expected?

Comment: `mdadm --monitor --scan --test --oneshot` will send an email reporting a TestMessage event for each RAID array on your system.

Comment: Seems like I could add `mdadm --monitor --scan --test` to the `/etc/rc.local` file to enable monitoring at boot.  Is that reasonable?

Comment: You may need to add `--daemonise` to get it running in the background, but it should work fine.